# How to run project in VS code

Tags: javascript, output

```
var message = 'sussy baka';

console.log(message)
```

that was my code, but I cant seem to figure out how to run the project in the "output" section
when I save it then click on it it just opens the actual code instead of putting in the output section.

***pls help***

Comment: "then click on it" — Click on what, precisely?

Comment: Is this Node? If it is, try running `node <file>.js` in the terminal.

Comment: Please don't ever use `var`